# match `"abc", "d,e", , "", ",f"` with groups

Tags: regex

I would like to regex-match the string

```
"abc", "d,e"  , "", ",f"
```

such that the groups `abc`, `d,e`, ``, and  `,f` (without quotes) are separately matched.

With the group

```
"([^"]*)"
```

matching the `"abc"` bits, I assumed the regex

```
(?:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*,)\s*"([^"]*)"\s*
```

would do the trick. However, it only matches `abc` and `d,e`.

I've created [a toy example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eP6vQ4/1) that shows the behavior.

Any hints?

Comment: You need `g`-Global flag or `findAll` or `matchAll` or similar thing on first regex. Check [`"([^"]*)"` with `g` flag](https://regex101.com/r/tA3yJ3/1).

Comment: What language are you using to perform the regex? I think it's correct to say that most will provide you with the context of 'next match', in which case I think you could use your first example - `"([^"]*)"`, and repeatedly call `get next match` as long as there are matches remaining.

Comment: What exactly you need to match? Exactly the string you have posted or every string with words or letters, divided by ',' in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to make "following" group optional:

```
(?:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*)(?:,\s*"([^"]*)"\s*)?
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/qH6hE6/1)**

### Update #1

Cleaner RegEx:

```
/\s*"([^"]+)"(?:,\s*)?/g
```

### Update #2

Base on your last edit for including zero or more characters:

```
/\s*"([^"]*?)"(?:,\s*)?/g
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP6vQ4/4)**

Comment: The string in the quotes can be empty, so replacing the respective `*` by `+` in your Update would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

Almost similar to revo's answer, but here's my regex:

```
/(?:"([^"]*)")(?:\s*,\s*)?/g
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM7kR7/1)

This will get correct match for `"abc" , "d,e"  , "", ",f"` also.